# "The image <name> cannot be displayed because it contains errors" when using pchart Render method

Tags: php, html, firefox, pchart

I am trying to use the pchart package (over php) to build (and directly display) graphs/charts.
At this time, I am just trying to run their provided example (`Example1.php`), where I just have replaced the final:

```
$Test->Render("example1.png");
```

by

```
$Test->Stroke();
```

But When I do this, I get:" The image  cannot be displayed because it contains errors" on the browser.
If I leave the original `$Test->Render(...)` the generated image is OK. (but not sent)

I have read that there is (was?) an issue with mozilla/Firefox browsers regarding images being required twice and the REFER URL, but when I browse at the pchart home page, I can use their "sanboxes" and get the result of my tests directly displayed on my browser (http://pchart.sourceforge.net/demo.php).
...
So their must be a way (or a nice work around) to send the generated graphs directely to the browser successfuly.

If your answer is to generate the image (i.e. use Render) and then send it afterwards, please but accurate on how to do this (how do I destroy the generated files automaticaly, permissions...)

I am new to this, sorry advance if it's obvious...;-)

Comment: I've found the same problem. See my ticket at bugtacker: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2991928&group_id=227755&atid=1071632

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have anything outside the `<?php ?>` brackets...this will send that whitespace or whatever *before* the image data, causing general chaos and badness.

Barring that, try adding a `header("Content-type: image/png");` to the top of the script, I doubt that would help but you never know...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know PChart, but stuff like this is most often down to PHP error messages polluting the PNG image.

Try saving the damaged image to disk, and opening it with an Editor like Notepad++. See whether there is anything meaningful in the first few lines of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Sylae answer is right! Make sure you don't have anything outside the , before and after it. Not even single space.